# Libgdx OrthographicCamera - How to set graphical objects always to center?

Tags: libgdx, alignment, android-camera

I have defined VIEWPORT_WIDTH and VIEWPORT_HEIGHT values. After that I would like to set all my objects to the center of this area.
By default I see all of my graphical items, sprites at the left corner. I use now this code:

```
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f, camera.viewportHeight/2f, 0);
```

How can I set "always center"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `OrthographicCamera` is always looking directly at its center. The center is equal to the `position` of an `OrthographicCamera`.

Thus, if you want to center your camera onto a certain object, you set the camera's position to the position of what you are trying to center on. For example:

```
camera.position.set(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), 0);
```

Comment: And don't forget to call `camera.update()`, which updates the projection and view matrix

Comment: I use two different kind of objects, which are drawed by ShapeRenderer. How can I set the center of this "complex" object?

Comment: @KovacsAkos Well, you need to determine the "middle" (kind of like the center of gravity) of those two objects and then set it as the position of the camera.

Comment: Yeah, I see, but I do not know the process of determination.

Comment: @KovacsAkos I think it should be sufficient if you just add the position of both parts together and then devide the result by 2. That should give you the simple average.

Comment: Okay, but I am using Sprites and also Shapes. How can I get the coordinates of Shapes?